# SBT to run Play app exits immediately when started using scala.sys.process.run?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am writing an integration test that needs to start up several applications. One of these applications is a Play one as a SBT project called `appA`.

I am able to start the app on the right port using `scala.sys.process` as follows:

```
import scala.sys.process._
import org.scalatest._

class Main extends FeatureSpec with Matchers{
  val app = Seq("sbt", "project appA", "run 7777").run
  println(app.exitValue)
}
```

The spawned application however exits immediately with return value `0`.  No errors are displayed to the console. I just see:

```
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:3000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)


[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Feb 27, 2014 10:26:56 PM
0
```

The 0 at the end of the output is from calling `exitValue` on the created process. `exitValue` blocks until the spawned process exits.

How can I run the Play application without it exiting immediately? Is there a better way to start the application?

Comment: Does it print any errors when it runs sbt?

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov No, no errors. I edited the question to show this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SBT has 2 run modes - interactive and batch. If you run without any args it goes to interactive mode and does not exit. When you run it by passing commands it runs in a batch mode and exits when the last command is complete. It does not matter if your application inside SBT runs in a forked JVM or not.

Thus to "fix" it you can apply this hack: add `~` command to the end of the list of sbt commands/args:

```
val app = Seq("sbt", "project appA", "run 7777", "~").run
```

`~` is used to watch source code for changes and recompile when it happens. Thus SBT will never exit unless stopped by a user or killed.

A cleaner way would be to run Play application in a Jetty container (assuming you have WAR to run) or such by calling a main class that starts up Jetty with a command like `java com.example.MyMain` but that requires additional setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The hack did solve the issue of sbt closing. Even though the process doesn't exit anymore until I kill it, the play application itself still exits immediately for some reason. Any ideas on how to stop this? I would prefer not to create a jar or war and just run the application as I usually do.

Comment: @mushroom for me the web application keeps running. Maybe it has to do with how you run it and what type of application it is. It would help to see your Boot or Main class.

Comment: For me, changing the command from "run" to "start" made it so that the app no longer exits. I don't know what difference this would make. I ended up creating a jar and starting it that way. Accepting your answer.